# Jquery find nearest matching element

Tags: jquery, dom-traversal

I have a series of rows with columns and I want to select the value of an `input` field that is in a previous column to the `input` field (price input) that I am calling a function on when a key is released.

I have tried:

```
quantity = $(this).parent().parent().children().val() ;
quantity = $(this).parent().parent().children().closest('.inputQty', this).val() ;
```

But neither work.

An example of the DOM:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="column"><input class="inputQty" id="quantity0" /></div>
    <div class="column"><input class="someOther" id="Other0" /></div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="cSelect">
            <select id="currency0"><option>£</option></select>
            <input class="price" id="price0" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 168, accepted):

```
var otherInput = $(this).closest('.row').find('.inputQty');
```

That goes up to a row level, then back down to `.inputQty`.

Comment: Is there no other function that looks for something on the same level as the element you're currently on? Do you always have to go up and back down?

Comment: This question wasn't about finding something on the same level - it was necessary to go up then back down - but yes, for the same level there's `.siblings()` and various `next~()` and `prev~()` methods.

Comment: thanks I was looking for a solution like that and it worked for me! but most important i learn more about closest() function. Thank you so much!

Davide,

Comment: Thanks tired with almost everything at last it worked for me :)

Answer (score 14):

`closest()` only looks for parents, I'm guessing what you really want is [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
$(this).closest('.row').children('.column').find('.inputQty').val();
```

Answer (score 2):

Get the `.column` parent of the `this` element, get its previous sibling, then find any input there:

```
$(this).closest(".column").prev().find("input:first").val();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aWhtP/

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

`$(this).closest(".column").prev().find(".inputQty").val();`