# Select id closest to id with pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<div>
  <div id="div2">TEXT</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div id="div2">TEXT</div> <!-- select this -->
</div>

<div id="div1">TEXT</div>
```

How to select div2 that is closest to div1

Comment: Please add more information to your question. Thanks!

Comment: `id` attribute should be unique in each HTML page.

Comment: Switch from `id` to class. IDs can not be repeated. Once you switch to classes, you can follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11756529/jquery-find-nearest-matching-element

Answer (score 1):

Following w3 [docs](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2)

> id = name [CS] 
> This attribute assigns a name to an element. This name must be unique in a document.

So make sure your elements id are unique. Can switch to class instead

To select element closet to target element can use `Element.closest()`

> The closest() method traverses the Element and its parents (heading toward the document root) until it finds a node that matches the provided selector string. Will return itself or the matching ancestor. If no such element exists, it returns null

```js
<div id="div-01">Here is div-01
   <div id="div-02">Here is div-02
     <div id="div-03">Here is div-03</div>
   </div>
</div>

var el = document.getElementById('div-03');

var r1 = el.closest("#div-02");
// returns the element with the id=div-02
```